# Having problems evaluating some limits

Tags: limits

1.$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{sinx})$

2.$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\Pi }{4} }(1-tanx)(sec2x)$

3.$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }x(2^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)$ (express the limits in terms of $t=\frac{1 }{x}$)

4.$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$

I tried question 1 ,but I have no idea how to do 2,3 and 4.
 here is what I did with 1

1.since $-1<sinx<1$,and $x$ can't equal to $0$, so the limits should be $x>1$

Comment: Are you familiar with L'Hospital's Rule? That will handle all of them. (There are other ways.) The limit of the first turns out to be $0$, by L'Hospital's Rule or power series.

Comment: Kinda blured about those things.I think I learnt it a few years back. I dont think I know it now, can u explain bt using the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the problems can be done by using L'Hospital's Rule. Please read about it, say in Wikipedia, specially for the conditions under which it can be applied.  Please note that the Rule can only be applied when we are dealing with certain types of "indeterminate forms."

Problem 1 has already been dealt with by Kevin.

For Problem 2, rewrite our function as $\frac{1-\tan x}{\cos 2x}$. Note that as $x\to \pi/4$, top and bottom approach $0$. So by L'Hospital's Rule, our limit is equal to 
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/4} \frac{-\sec^2 x}{-2\sin 2x}.$$
Now we are finished, the new top and bottom behave nicely as $x\to\pi/4$. The top approaches $-2$, as does the bottom, so the limit is $1$.

For Problem 3, rewrite our function as $\frac{2^{1/x}-1}{1/x}$. Then top and bottom approach $0$. We could apply L'Hospital's Rule directly, but it is convenient to let $t=1/x$. So we want 
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{2^t-1}{t}.$$
To apply L'Hospital's rule, we need to differentiate top and bottom. The derivative of the top will be clearer if we note that $2^t=e^{(\ln 2) t}$. So the derivative of the top is $(\ln 2) 2^t$. The derivative of the bottom is $1$. So we conclude that our limit is $\ln 2$.

For Problem 4, rewrite our function as $e^{\frac{\ln x}{1-x}}$.  We find the limit as $x\to 1$ of the exponent $\frac{\ln x}{1-x}$. Note that top and bottom of the exponent approach $0$ as $x\to 1$. A routine application of L'Hospital's Rule shows that
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\ln x}{1-x}=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1/x}{-1}=-1.$$
So the exponent has limit $-1$, and therefore the original expression has limit $e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for #2: Using the trigonometric double angle identity $\cos{2x}=\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}$,

$$\left(1-\tan{x}\right)\sec{2x}=\frac{\cos{x}-\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}}=\frac{\sec{x}}{\cos{x}+\sin{x}}.$$

Hint for #4: Substitute $h=\frac{1}{1-x}$. Then $\frac{1}{h}=1-x\implies x=1-\frac{1}{h}$, and the left-handed limit comes to,

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}=\lim_{h\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{h}\right)^h,$$

which defines a familiar mathematical constant. Don't forget to compute the right-handed limit $\lim_{x\to 1^+}x^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$ too. If it equals the left-handed limit found above, then the two-sided limit exists and is equal to this value.

Comment: is this means that the limit is x cant equal to 0 and $\pi/2$

Comment: @user136877 I don't understand what you are trying to ask. Please rephrase.

Comment: I mean the anser for question 1

Comment: @user136877 I didn't discuss question #1 at all. I only addressed questions #2 and #4 in my response.

Comment: I mean for question 2,got confused

Comment: @user136877 Okay, question #2 then. Could you please rephrase your question using correct grammar? I'd really like to help you and answer your question, but I just don't understand. =/

Comment: So as you stated above that $\frac{\sec{x}}{\cos{x}+\sin{x}}$, for the denominator $cosx\neq 0$,$x\neq \pi/2$. $sinx\neq 0$, $x\neq 0$. Is this the limits?

Answer (score 0):

Example of L'Hopital for problem 1:

Since trying to take the limit directly ends up with something undefined (i.e. $\infty-\infty$) we need to apply L'Hopital, that is take derivatives of the numerator and denominator and apply the limit again.

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{sin (x)}=lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{sin(x)-x}{x~sin(x)}=lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{cos(x)-1}{sin(x)+x~cos(x)}=lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{-sin(x)}{cos(x)+cos(x)-sin(x)}=0$$

The first application doesn't do the trick because we are back to an indeterminate form 0/0.  So just apply it again to get the answer.